# How do I facet by geom / layer in ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet-wrap, facet-grid

I'm hoping to recreate the `gridExtra` output below with `ggplot`'s facet_grid, but I'm unsure of what variable `ggplot` identifies with the layers in the plot.  In this example, there are two geoms...

```
require(tidyverse)

a <- ggplot(mpg)
b <- geom_point(aes(displ, cyl, color = drv))
c <- geom_smooth(aes(displ, cyl, color = drv))
d <- a + b + c

# output below
gridExtra::grid.arrange(
  a + b,
  a + c,
  ncol = 2
) 

# Equivalent with gg's facet_grid
# needs a categorical var to iter over...
d$layers
#d + facet_grid(. ~ d$layers??)
```

The gridExtra output that I'm hoping to recreate is:

[image]

Comment: Faceting is designed for "small multiples", multiple copies of the same plot for different data subsets. For what you want, grid.arrange is the right tool.

Comment: @Gregor I agree, but my thought here is that the # of layers (2) is a small multiple that `gg` obviously can see since its in the list `d`... I wouldn't have thought I have to appeal to an external package in this case...

Comment: "I agree but I disagree" doesn't seem like you agree... You're trying to make different plots of the same data, not the same plot of different (subsets of) data

Comment: On https://r4ds.had.co.nz/data-visualisation.html section 3.6, you see a perfectly good example of where this type of view across geoms would be used.  if it makes you feel better for me to not call it a facet then lets call it a view and drop a feature request, thanks @Gregor

Comment: Agree with what @Gregor says. I understand the use case of putting two related charts side by side like the R4DS example, but those weren't done by facetting. Why not use the right tools for the right job? `patchwork` is one ggplot layout package that doesn't add more than a few functions to your environment if that's your concern. You could even rig up something like the classic [`multiplot`](http://www.cookbook-r.com/Graphs/Multiple_graphs_on_one_page_(ggplot2)/) based just on packages `ggplot2` loads (which are plentiful)

Comment: Also an aside: [small multiples](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Small_multiple) doesn't refer to the number of plots or layers, but the technique of making repeated copies of the same chart with some aspect of the data changed, such as is done with the facet functions

Comment: @camille so the fact that the grob is a list that already contains the information necessary to do this (the `.$layers` object) doesn't convince you that this should be a feature of `ggplot2`? There are two very simple "hacks" given below that accomplish this task.  I realize that a lot of the time in R the answer is "just install another package" but I'd like to avoid that mentality if possible.

Comment: You can also look at how this is done in code [in the R4DS code](https://github.com/hadley/r4ds/blob/d1a63fe379004d2ace9ce790e0f89c441c221bea/visualize.Rmd#L304), two separate plots, aligned side-by-side by `knitr` (or `bookdown`, or whatever)

Comment: No one's saying *this isn't useful*, or *don't do this*, and certainly no one said *this would be a terrible feature that should never be part of `ggplot2`*. We're saying that facets / small multiples have a pretty clear definition (which is embedded into how they're implemented), and **this is something different.** It might be nice if `ggplot` offered a way to align different plots side-by-side, but it doesn't and many other packages have stepped in to provide that functionality in different ways.

Comment: That said, this *particular* functionality--different layers on different subplots--seems niche to me. One would want to be able to clearly specify which layers go in which subplot, the subplot labels should be optional and often unused (unlike in faceting, where the facet strip labels are almost always needed to tell the difference between the data subsets). One could write a function for this, and the ggplot maitainers would be happy if you put it in a package, but I doubt they would welcome it into the core `ggplot2` package without loads of testing and a strong case made for its need.

Comment: All excellent points.  Thank you @Gregor and @ camille

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A hacky way of doing this is to take the existing data frame and create two, three, as many copies of the data frame you need with a value linked to it to be used for the facet and filtering later on. Union (or rbind) the data frames together into one data frame. Then set up the ggplot and geoms and filter each geom for the desired attribute. Also for the facet use the existing attribute to split the plots.

This can be seen below:

```
df1 <- data.frame(
      graph = "point_plot",
      mpg
    )
df2 <- data.frame(
    graph = "spline_plot",
    mpg
  )

df <- rbind(df1, df2)

ggplot(df, mapping = aes(x = displ, y = hwy, color = class)) +
  geom_point(data = filter(df, graph == "point_plot")) +
  geom_smooth(data = filter(df, graph == "spline_plot"), se=FALSE) +
  facet_grid(. ~ graph)
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If you really want to show different plots on different facets, one hacky way would be to make separate copies of the data and subset those...

```
mpg2 <- mpg %>% mutate(facet = 1) %>%
  bind_rows(mpg %>% mutate(facet = 2))

ggplot(mpg2, aes(displ, cyl, color = drv)) +
  geom_point(data = subset(mpg2, facet == 1)) +
  geom_smooth(data = subset(mpg2, facet == 2)) +
  facet_wrap(~facet)
```

[image]